# How to proove that $\arctan(3/4)$ is not commensurable with $\pi$?

Tags: group-theory

How to prove that $\arctan(3/4)$ is not commensurable with $\pi = 3.14\ldots$?

This is an exercise from E.B.Vinberg "Course of Algebra" (exercise 4.38)

Comment: it's in Niven, Irrational Numbers. The only $\arctan \frac{m}{n}$ that are commensurable with $\pi$ are the obvious ones.

Comment: Thank you Will. This exercise is from "Cyclic groups" chapter. I think there is another solution using cyclic group.

Comment: If I don't mistake, one of the parts of the Lambert's proof of irrationality of pi was that tangent of rational number (in radians) is always an irrational number. So if tangent of some number is 3/4 that means it is irrational number. Maybe, it can help you, so if it will, then find Lambert's proof on the internet.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36272/when-is-arctan-a-rational-multiple-of-pi) might help.

Comment: Just compute $(4+3i)^n$ modulo $5$. The commesurability means that there is some $n$ for which this number is real. But mod 5 it cycles on the numbers $\pm\{1,2\}\pm\{1,2\}i$.

Comment: @Metso What is/are the *previous* exercise(s) in the same book? Could it be that the author is preparing you for this exercise by giving you the groundwork in the previous exercises?

Comment: @user8734617 prev. exercise: prove that the order of any element of the group $Sn$ does
not exceed $e^{n/e}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what machinery it is expected to be used to solve this problem. Still...

If $\alpha=\arctan\frac{3}{4}$ and $\pi$ were commensurable, then it would be true that $p\alpha=q\pi$ for some integers $p,q\ne 0$. Take $z=\frac{4}{5}+\frac{3}{5}i$: then $z=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$. Thus $z^p=\cos(p\alpha)+i\sin(p\alpha)=\cos(q\pi)+i\sin(q\pi)=\pm 1$.

Now this means that $(5z)^p=(4+3i)^p=\pm 5^q$. Note that $4+3i=i(2-i)^2$, so:

$$i^p(2-i)^{2p}=\pm(2+i)^p(2-i)^p$$

Cancelling $(2-i)^p$, we get:

$$i^p(2-i)^p=\pm(2+i)^p$$

which is impossible because, in the ring $\mathbb Z[i]$ of Gaussian integers, $2-i$ and $2+i$ are distinct prime elements, so the unique factorisation would be violated.